# GIMP Scaling Groups of layer masks

Tags: gimp, layers, mask, scale

Using GIMP it's possible to link a number of layers together and scale them together. However I have about 5 layers each with a layer mask that fit together - I would like to scale these together with the scale tool. If I link the layers together only the mask I scale appears to be affected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the layer is active when you are scaling. This is indicated by a white outline around the layer in the layers dialog:

[image: layers dialog, layer is active]

If the layer mask is active, then the scale tool will only scale that one layer mask. Again, this is indicated by a white outline around the layer mask in the layers dialog:

[image: layers dialog, layer mask active]